# MUI breakpoints inside Stickybits breaks Stickybits

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I encountered the problem with applying MUI breakpoints. I'm trying to be able to set a dynamic offset for the sticky header using MUI breakpoints. No syntax errors, just stop working as expected.

I'm using this package called stickybits, it's basically the same thing as the css poosition sticky except it has some handy features that will allow me to apply some classes when the header is pinned. Anywho, I'm new to MUI and react in general, but for the most part I have a solid understanding what I'm doing. So for the header I still I have to apply an offset, but the offset is based off the screen size.

So this is easily done normally with the MUI breakpoints. Well, appearently for some reason it breaks the sticky package because when I apply the MUI breakpoints inside of the stickyBitStickyOffset, the offset works fine but then it breaks the rest of the options. Like I have an option set for a specific class for when the header is stuck, and it works fine if I use just a regular Integer value, but when I use an object so I can insert the different break points it stops applying the 'stuck' class. I'm confused as to why, I get zero syntax errors so I'm just left wondering what's going wrong.

Here is the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/stickybits

And here is the code that'll work just fine:

```
   const sticky = stickybits(stickyHeader.current, {
      stickyBitStickyOffset: 98,
      useStickyClasses: true,
      stickyClass: "stuck",
    });
```

This however will break it.

```
    const sticky = stickybits(stickyHeader.current, {
      stickyBitStickyOffset: {
        [theme.breakpoints.only("desktop")]: 98,
        [theme.breakpoints.up("desktop")]: 168,
      },
      useStickyClasses: true,
      stickyClass: "stuck",
    });
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: Nobody has any ideas?